# How can I get my textbox to update from an Asyncpostback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asyncpostbackerror

I have an update panel set up with a trigger for an async post back. Here's the code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:updatePanel ID="tableUpdate" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CreateLinkToQuery" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="CreateLinkToQuery" CssClass="myButton" runat="server" Text="Create Link To Query" OnClick="CreateLinkToQuery_Click"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="QueryData" CssClass="popInnerContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

And here is the codebehind:

```
protected void CreateLinkToQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QueryData.Text = "wwww.whateverlinkIfeelLike.com";
}
```

When the button is clicked if I add the control to watch then it certainly updates it with the new text, however on the UI nothing happens and if I spy the control in Firefox it shows as being empty.

I cannot understand where i'm going wrong here.

1 thing to note that this update panel is within a JQuery dialog

Here is the code im using for that:

```
$('#CreateQuery').click(function (event) {

    var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 730,
    minWidth: 730,
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $("#dialog").hide();
    }
    });
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery('form:first'));
});
```

Comment: hope this help [link](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx)

Comment: Hiya I tried this and sadly it still didnt update the form